# performing operations on values in 2-D list and appending each sub-list to new list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, append

I have two 2-D python array lists. I want to on each value in each array perform an operation on each other and append that value into a list while retaining the 2-D structure.

For example I have

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list2 = [[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]]
```

I want to do so that (for example just simple addition) the output is

```
output_list: [[4,4,4],[10,10,10],[16,16,16]]
```

In my case, I am calculating the standard deviation.

I have two 2-D lists named `rolling_mean` and `mean_std` that I am doing parallel iteration over and appending to an list named `lower_bound`

```
lower_bound = []
    

    for k,h in zip(range(len(rolling_mean)),range(len(mean_std))):
        for l,m in zip(range(len(rolling_mean[k])),range(len(mean_std[h]))):
            lower_bound.append(rolling_mean[k][l] - (1.96 * mean_std[h][m]))

    print(lower_bound)
```

This is giving me the correct output but the values are all in one single array. I want it to be a 2-D array like the example output above.

Comment: How does "simple addition" get your last sublist to be `[9,8,7]`?

Comment: Instead of using `range(...)`, you could use the list itself: `[[l - (1.96 * m) for l, m in zip(k, h)] for k, h in zip(rolling_mean, mean_std)]`

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for pointing that out my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
lb_part = []
for l,m ...
    lb_part.append(...)
lower_bound.append(lb_part)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic functions `reczip` and `recmap` may be useful to you -

```py
def reczip(a,b,f=tuple):
  if isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
    return list(reczip(v, b[i], f) for (i,v) in enumerate(a))
  else:
    return f((a,b))
```

```py
x = [[1,2,3],[[4],[5,6]],9]
y = [[3,2,1],[[6],[5,4]],9]
```

```py
print(reczip(x,y))
```

```py
[[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)], [[(4, 6)], [(5, 5), (6, 4)]], (9, 9)]
```

```py
def recmap(a,f):
  if isinstance(a, list):
    return list(recmap(v, f) for v in a)
  else:
    return f(a)
```

```py
print(recmap(reczip(x,y),sum))
```

```py
[[4, 4, 4], [[10], [10, 10]], 18]
```

As you can see, these work on lists of any nesting level. However, if `reczip` encounters an asymmetrical shape, you can handle accordingly -

```py
def reczip(a,b,f=tuple):
  try:
    if isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
      return list(reczip(v, b[i], f) for (i,v) in enumerate(a))
    else:
      return f((a,b))
  except IndexError:
    return f((a,b)) # when a and b have different number of elements
```